# How to bind a variable in parse block

Tags: rebol

I just want to iterate through a list of file and after parsing its content print the name of the file:

```
files: [%test1.txt %test2.txt]
rule: [to "test" thru "test" copy x to "." (print x print file)]
foreach file files [
    content: read file
    parse [any rule]
]
```

when executing I have 
** Script error: file has no value

How can I bind file var name to the context of rule block program ?

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to do it this way (put in the RULE literally and let FOREACH to bind it at the right time):

```
files: [%test1.txt %test2.txt]
rule: [to "test" thru "test" copy x to "." (print x print file)]
foreach file files compose/only/deep [
    content: read file
    parse content [any (rule)]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to bind the rule each iteration:

```
files: [%test1.txt %test2.txt]
rule: [to "test" thru "test" copy x to "." (print x print file)]
foreach file files [
    bind rule 'file
    content: read file
    parse content [any rule]
]
```